# jetty 9 and apache xml rpc 3.1.3: Premature end of file

Tags: java, apache, jetty, xml-rpc

I have to support some old XML RPC service. After upgrade from jetty 6 to 9 I get the following error:

```
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Failed to parse XML-RPC request: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.getRequest(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:71)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:199)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServletServer.execute(XmlRpcServletServer.java:112)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.XmlRpcServlet.doPost(XmlRpcServlet.java:196)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This error does not occur on every request, but arises periodically, which seems to indicate some threading problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Make sure that you use "Content-Type: application/xml" in requests' headers.